# HTML5 block level elements failing in IE with HTML5Shiv or Modernizr

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, html5shiv

I have HTML5Shiv/Modernizr (I have tried both in case), along with normalize which assigns `display: block` to HTML5 elements like `section` and `article`.

In IE8, `display: block` does not seem to get correctly assigned to HTML5 elements.

I have done a test console log on the JavaScript to make sure it is called, and also tried removing some of the CSS in case the selector limit had been reached, and moving/reordering the CSS and JS around.

Any other Gotchas?

Comment: I do not thing IE8 supports html 5...

Comment: @Pilatus that's why you use html5shiv/modernizr

Comment: You should probably be setting a display of block in a reset stylesheet anyway. Random site example: http://vikaskhera.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/html5-reset-stylesheet/

Comment: Can you post the HTML and CSS fragments? Did you look at it with the Developer Tools (F12)?

Comment: be aware that the shim for IE should be loaded on the head of your document (before the css), otherwise it may not work as you expected

Answer (score 6):

Issue resolved.

Turns out one of the nav elements had an odd attribute xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" assigned to it which was completely throwing the html5 shiv script and preventing it from processing anything below this line.

Comment: Wait a moment, you've declared an `xmlns` attribute on `nav` element, like for example `<header><nav xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">...</nav></header>`?

Comment: HAH! This detail just helped me out. I have SVG elements and they had namespaces in them. Stripped that code out of them, and boom! HTML5 elements working in IE8 w/ Modernizr. So, go figure.

Answer (score -1):

As Fabrizio says the only real issue could be that you're not loading modenizr before any of your other scripts or HTML. It should be loaded in the head, while your other scripts should be in the footer.

Maybe download the boilerplate framework just to see how it should all be done - http://html5boilerplate.com

Regards,

Dave

Comment: Yes, the stylesheets and JS are loaded in the head. I have also tried moving HTML5 Shiv to the very top of the head. Odd thing is there is a <header> element at the top of my page which is getting display: block assigned, which leads me to believe it could be a missing closing tag or similar perhaps.